# SQLite SELECT...ordering by "best" match

Tags: sqlite, select

The context here is a SQLCipher database in an Android app.
The context here is a SQLCipher database in an Android app.
The context here is a SQLCipher database in an Android app. Consider the following SQLite table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(a INTEGER NOT NULL,b INTEGER NOT NULL,c INTEGER NOT NULL,d INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

into which I insert the following rows

```
INSERT INTO test (a,b,c,d) VALUES(1,2,3,4);
INSERT INTO test (a,b,c,d) VALUES(1,2,3,5);
INSERT INTO test (a,b,c,d) VALUES(1,2,5,5);
INSERT INTO test (a,b,c,d) VALUES(1,5,5,5);
INSERT INTO test (a,b,c,d) VALUES(5,5,5,5);
```

A simple `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE a = 1 OR b = 2 or c = 3 or d = 4;` would return `4` as the result since 4 of the 5 rows have one or more matching values.  What I need to do is to find the "best" match, i.e. the one that satisfies the most `WHERE .. OR` conditions.  In the present instance this would return the first row where **all four** columns match. While I could simply get a cursor back on a raw select along the lines of `SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = 1 OR b = 2 or c = 3 or d = 4;` and then do the rest in Java I am wondering if there isn't a way to do this directly within SQLite itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the expression:

```
(a=1) + (b=2) + (c=3) + (d=4)
```

in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
ORDER BY (a=1) + (b=2) + (c=3) + (d=4) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Each of the terms: `(a=1)`, `(b=2)`, `(c=3)` and `(d=4)` evaluates to `1` for `TRUE` or `0` for `FALSE`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8tn739H79gSCc32T7pf7pt/0).
If you want ties in the results use a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, (a=1) + (b=2) + (c=3) + (d=4) counter
  FROM test
)
SELECT a, b, c, d 
FROM cte
WHERE counter = (SELECT MAX(counter) FROM cte)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8tn739H79gSCc32T7pf7pt/2).
Or with `RANK()` window function:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (a=1) + (b=2) + (c=3) + (d=4) DESC) rn
  FROM test
)
SELECT a, b, c, d 
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8tn739H79gSCc32T7pf7pt/3).
Results:

```
| a   | b   | c   | d   |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | 2   | 3   | 4   |
```

Comment: On reflection after having posted the question I had realized that at times I would need not just the "best" match but perhaps the top 2 or 3 "best" matches in order.  As it turns out you answered that question too! Your `RANK()` example with the condition changed to `WHERE rn < 3`, for example, would return the first and second best matches.

Comment: One further question - would a `CREATE INDEX test_ndx ON test(a,b,c,d)` result in a faster query here?

Comment: I don't think so because you don't need to filter or sort on a,b,c,d, but the expression `(a=1) + (b=2) + (c=3) + (d=4)`. But you can test it.

Comment: @DroidOS if you want *the top 3 "best" matches in order* check also DENSE_RANK() instead of RANK() with rn <= 3 to include all the ties.

Comment: A WARNING for anyone who sees this thread and tries to  use the ideas discussed here: Make sure that you have a recent version of SQLite.  I switched computers and suddenly found that @forpas code was no longer working.  A frustrating two hours later I realized that the other computer had version 3.22.2 instead of 3.31.1 where it does work.  The Android SQLCipher implementation is currently forked from SQLite 3.30.1 so I can only hope that this does work there.  Perhaps someone will be able to say when SQLite started fully supporting CTE.  I haven't found that information.

Comment: From: http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_3.html SQLite supports CTEs since version 3.8.3 and from: https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html supports window functions since version 3.25.0