# SQLite order results by smallest difference

Tags: sqlite, select, sql-order-by, dense-rank

In many ways this question follows on from my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60538227/sqlite-select-ordering-by-best-match).  I have a table that is pretty much identical

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test
(
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 a INTEGER NOT NULL,
 b INTEGER NOT NULL,
 c INTEGER NOT NULL,
 d INTEGER NOT NULL,
 weather INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

in which I would typically have entries such as

```
INSERT INTO test (a,b,c,d,weather) VALUES(1,2,3,4,30100306);
INSERT INTO test (a,b,c,d,weather) VALUES(1,2,3,4,30140306);
INSERT INTO test (a,b,c,d) VALUES(1,2,5,5,10100306);    
INSERT INTO test (a,b,c,d) VALUES(1,5,5,5,11100306);
INSERT INTO test (a,b,c,d) VALUES(5,5,5,5,21101306);
```

Typically this table would have multiple rows with the some/all of  b, c and d values being identical but with different a and weather values.  As per the answer to my other question I can certainly issue

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (b=2) + (c=3) + (d=4) DESC) rn FROM test where a = 1) SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn < 3;
```

No issues thus far.  However, I have one further requirement which arises as a result of the weather column.  Although this value is an integer it is in fact a composite where each digit represents a "banded" weather condition.  Take for example  `weather = 20100306`.  Here 2 represents the wind direction divided up into 45 degree bands on the compass, 0 represents a wind speed range, 1 indicates precipitation as snow etc. What I need to do now while obtaining my ordered results is to allow for weather differences.  Take for example the first two rows

```
INSERT INTO test (a,b,c,d,weather) VALUES(1,2,3,4,30100306);
INSERT INTO test (a,b,c,d,weather) VALUES(1,2,3,4,30140306);
```

Though otherwise similar they represent rather different weather conditions - the fourth number is four as opposed to 0 indicating a higher precipitation intensity brand. The `WITH cte...` above would rank the first two rows at the top which is fine.  But what if I would rather have the row that differs the **least** from an incoming "weather condition" of 30130306?  I would clearly like to have the second row appearing at the top.  Once again, I can live with the "raw" result returned by `WITH cte...` and then drill down to the right row based on my current "weather condition" in Java.  However, once again I find myself thinking that there is perhaps a rather neat way of doing this in SQL that is outwith my skill set.  I'd be most obliged to anyone who might be able to tell me how/whether this can be done using just SQL.

Comment: Yes - there was a typo.  Corrected now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the results 1st by `DENSE_RANK()` and 2nd by the absolute difference of `weather` and the incoming "weather condition":

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (b=2) + (c=3) + (d=4) DESC) rn 
  FROM test 
  WHERE a = 1
) 
SELECT a,b,c,d,weather 
FROM cte 
WHERE rn < 3
ORDER BY rn, ABS(weather - ?);
```

Replace `?` with the value of that *incoming "weather condition"*.

Comment: I had figured out that I would need to order by `ABS(weather - ?)` but was attempting to do it in the wrong elect - I mean in `WITH cte AS(...`.  Thank you!